# Stream videos from Azure blob storage and ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm using latest and recommended `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package. I'm uploading the video file as chunks, which works fine. The problem is now returning back the video to the web client, which is `videojs`. The player is using `Range` request.

My endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("video/{id}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetVideoStreamAsync(string id)
{
   var stream = await GetVideoFile(id);

   return File(stream, "video/mp4", true); // true is for enableRangeProcessing
}
```

And my `GetVideoFile` method

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(ms, null, new StorageTransferOptions
{
    InitialTransferLength = 1024 * 1024,
    MaximumConcurrency = 20,
    MaximumTransferLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024
});

ms.Position = 0;

return ms;
```

The video gets downloaded and streamed just fine. But it downloads the whole video and not respecting `Range` at all. I've also tried with `DownloadTo(HttpRange)`

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

// parse range header... 
var range = new HttpRange(from, to);
BlobDownloadInfo info = await blobClient.DownloadAsync(range);
await info.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
return ms;
```

But nothing gets displayed in the browser. What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question if someone comes across.

`CloudBlockBlob` (version I'm using: 11.2.2) now has `OpenReadAsync()` method which returns stream. In my case I'm returning this stream to `videojs` which handles the `Range` header on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by resetting the memory stream's position to `0` before returning:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();

// parse range header... 
var range = new HttpRange(from, to);
BlobDownloadInfo info = await blobClient.DownloadAsync(range);
await info.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
ms.Position = 0;//ms is positioned at the end of the stream so we need to reset that.
return ms;
```

Comment: Well, no.. still no video

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the front end code as well? I would like to simulate this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible to achieve it only using Azure Blob. More info in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26053910/1384539

but in summary, you can use a CDN that offers the Seek Start / End position : https://docs.vdms.com/cdn/re3/Content/Streaming/HPD/Seeking_Within_a_Video.htm

Another possibility is to use Azure Media Services that supports streamming. Your approach is actually a progressive download which is not exactly the same idea, and you'd probably spend a lot with network out. (assuming you have many access to the same file)