# How to display a video on the site without the user being able to download it in any way. In ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, blob

I am going to build an educational site where users will not have access to the original video file and will only be able to watch it through the site. Is there a way that the file is not recognized by the IDM plugin?

According to the articles I read on the Internet, blob can be used, but there was no solution for local use of Azure Storage blob.

Comment: Ultimately, Users can always film the Monitor with their Cell-Phone. Which means: you don't want it copied 100% == Don't send it. So what are you trying to protect? Is it _really that valuable_ that Joe Averageuser will jump all the hooves to pirate your video?

Comment: **(1)** _"Is there a way that the file is not recognized by the IDM plugin?"_ but no explanation of how it finds it on your page... For example do you mention the file name anywhere in the source code? Do you think it scans the page source for links? **(2)** There are solutions for MP4/MOV and solutions for WebM. Some solutions work on desktop but not on mobile. There are no solutions for a thing called _"video file"_. If you want a fast answer be specific with details about your problem. What video type? What browser? What platform(s) to support? (iPhone is least flexible for custom data).

Comment: PS: The fastest way is to modify the video bytes themselves (server-side) in such a way that any downloader ends up with an playable file. Your code (client side) should correctly re-structure the bytes then send to your playback system (are you using an HTML5 video tag? or else is it some C# media player component? Option 2: Consider using an encryption system like AES. Investigate if usable to you (you might need to download a special encoder to encrypt all your other existing videos)... First option does not need backups, second one does (for in case AES key is lost in future)

Comment: I want that no professional user (familiar with html, js structure) or beginner user can download the video.
Please explain the use of AES.

Comment: Please explain about sending the file piece by piece.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of preventing downloads via browser plugins like IDM, you can use
streaming to send the video content in small chunks rather than as a single file. This can make it hard for plugins to intercept and download the entire file. Azure Blob Storage supports "pseudo streaming" of video content via the "Range" header in HTTP requests. This can be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15166547/13105803

Or another option is to use [Azure media service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/)

Comment: I don't want to use azure servers because in my country international internet is not good.